# does autodesk forge (viewer) supportes spatial functions

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

i want to know if i can perform some spatial function using autodesk forge.

for example intersect - contains - touches - within ...

if i can write an extension that will allow me to draw a polygon and select (or get somehow) the ids of all objects inside it.

i have found this blog https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/area-planning-tool-forge-viewer-and-mysql and i would like to know if instead of getting the area of the polygon, i can get the elements within it.

thank you!!

Comment: Forge viewer has no builtin tool for that but it is built on top of three.js. So if you find a way to do in three.js you can probably do it in forge viewer.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, you can start by getting the THREE.Box for a Forge Viewer element, then use box methods as you need.